# redeclared as different kind of symbol error in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I get the error 'J_TypeInstructions' redeclared as different kind of symbol' in the following C code:

```
struct _J_TypeInstructions {
    const char *instructionName;
} J_TypeInstructions[] = { { "j", "000010" } };
//typedef struct _J_TypeInstructions J_TypeInstructions;
```

Comment: What is the commented-out line of code there for? Is that the line that is giving you the error? Because if you uncomment that, you are trying to give a name that was used for a variable to a typedef. And typedefs are a bit like variable types - you can't have an `int` called `float`... Same thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`J_TypeInstructions` can't be both variable name and type.

First, you created a variable(an array of _J_TypeInstructions structures) called `J_TypeInstructions`

then you try to define type with the same name as previously defined array.

Also, as **ouah**  mentioned in his answer, fix your braces because the way you use them now is try to initialize one char * with 2 values and that's definetelly giving you a warning.

Comment: It is not exactly the same name, there is a leading underscore in the struct type name. Also, it is perfectly legal in C to have a struct type and a variable with the same name.

Comment: @SirDarius Array of structures and typedef has exactly the same name (without underscore).

Comment: if you are mentioning the part that's commented out, well then, I didn't really pay attention to it, because, well, commented out :)

Comment: @SirDarius Yes, I do. Because it's the part that's giving error mentioned by OP. I don't have a clue why he commented out the most vital part of his question. :)

Comment: +1, I missed the commented line which is the error the OP was complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

Try with that instead:

```
struct _J_TypeInstructions {
    const char *instructionName;
} J_TypeInstructions[] = { {"j"}, {"000010"} };

                          /*   ^  ^  */
```

and do not use a tag name like `_J_TypeInstructions` as identifiers beginning with `_[A-Z]*` are reserved in C.

**EDIT**: I missed the commented line was a part of the question:

```
typedef struct _J_TypeInstructions J_TypeInstructions;
```

You already declared a variable with the identifier `J_TypeInstructions`. You cannot declare a type with the same name of a variable in the same scope as identifiers for variables and type names live in the same name space. Change the name of your variable to fix the issue.